# Java Error: The constructor is undefined Anylogic Simulation Software

Tags: java, anylogic

I can't solve this Error:
Description: The constructor Request(int, Suppliers) is undefined. Location: testing/Suppliers/requestSupplier - Event

This is the Code:

```
Request request = new Request(uniform_discr(10,20), this);
Vehicle truck = getNearestAgentByRoute(filter(main.vehicles,
                v -> v.inState(Vehicle.AtFactory)));
if (truck != null)
send (request, truck);
```

[Screenshot Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc65r.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not instantiate agents this way (like Java classes). Always add them to an agent population using `add_MyRequestPopulation(...)` where the args are your agent parameters

So create an population of `Requests` and use the code above. Note that you need to specify all 4 parameters of your `Request` agent type

Comment: Thanks, I did it, But I have a question, I would like to build a supply chain model and using Blockchain library (web3j library) an import it to Anylogic to make the data storage on a Blockchain environment, do you know how can I do it ?

Comment: Happy to help but please always open new issues for new questions, SOF does not work like a chat. See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: I create a question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72114383/how-to-use-and-import-blockchain-library-web3j-on-anylogic