# How to Use and Import Blockchain Library (web3j) on Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic, web3js, web3-java

I'm a newbie on Anylogic, and I would like to build a Simple supply chain in a scenario where data will be stored in a Blockchain environment.
I have some pieces of advice from people that told me to use the web3j library, but I don't have any idea how to import it? Or how it works? or it is helpful for my vision.

Comment: Your question appears to be very open-ended - perhaps consider asking it on the LinkedIn User group. SOF is more suitable for specific technical questions - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I did already on Anylogic group, unfortunately there is no one answer me

Answer (score 0):

I'm really throwing this out there, but I guess if you extract the library files to the project's folder, added every single file to the dependencies list under "jar files and class folders" and then imported the classes you need in the "Imports section" under "Advanced Java" in the Main agent properties, that could be enough for you to be able have the library imported to your model.